# Shifting the items in an array by a specified value

Tags: php, arrays

How would you go about circularly rotating the items in an array up or down by a specified value. For example

```
$value = 1; // circularly rotate by 1
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5);

// Should return

array(2,3,4,5,1);
```

The entire array is circularly rotated anti-clockwise by 1. `1` went to the end and `2` became the leading number in the array. I cannot find a reliable way to do this.

Comment: What if `$value` is 2 ?

Comment: If the value was 2, the array would then be (3,4,5,1,2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for`-loop with a specification on how many items you want moved, and `array_shift()` to shift the array. Then add the first element to a shifted array (which essentially moves the first item to the last element)

```
$shift = 2; // How many times you want to move it
$output = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

for ($i = 0; $i < $shift; $i++) {
    array_push($output , array_shift($output));
}
print_r($output); // 3, 4, 5, 1, 2
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/QAgVS)

## References

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the `array_push` function that adds a value to the end of an array and the `array_shift` function that removes and returns the first element of an array.

```
<?php

$value = 1; // circularly rotate by 1
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5);

while ($value) {
    array_push($array, array_shift($array));
    $value--;
}

print_r($array);

?>
```